# cmake using find_package() cross compiling

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I am using CMake with a custom toolchain that I built using yocto. I have a problem though, the toolchain has sysroot for the target machine and one for the build machine.

CMake keeps finding the libraries in the build system sysroot only.

For example I am using:

```
find_package(libxml2)
```

But it always keeps finding libxml2 in the build system sysroot instead of the target sysroot. How can I tell it to only look in the target sysroot?

Answer (score 23):

> How can I tell it to look in the target sysroot only?

There is a family of CMake variables `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*`, which adjusts search strategy for different CMake commands:

- *BOTH* value means that both *target* and *host* (build) paths are searched. This is also a default behavior, when a variable is not set.
- *ONLY* value means that only *target* is searched.
- *NEVER* value means, that only *host* is searched.

List of variables:

- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html) affects on `find_library()` calls
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE.html) affects on `find_path()` and `find_file()` calls
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE.html) affects on `find_package()` in *CONFIG* mode (when `*Config.cmake` file is searched).
- [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html) affects on `find_program()` call.

Generally, concrete `find_package()` call may be affected by all of these variables. In case of searching libraries, it is usually suffificient to set only 3 of them:

```
# Search libraries only under *target* paths.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Variables `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` are normally set in toolchain files.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks