# FindGit not working on iOS cross-compile

Tags: git, cmake

We have a macOS where `git` is installed as part of XCode. It resides in `usr/bin`.

Now when we use `find_package(Git REQUIRED)` it does not find `git`.

- `which git` gives `/usr/bin/git`
- Using the `find_program` call in `FindGit.cmake` fails.
- When looking at `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, there is an entry for `/usr`.
- Tested CMake versions are 3.5 and 3.7.1
- It only fails for cross-compilation to iOS (via Toolchain file)

Really have no idea anymore why this fails.

Comment: Cleared your CMakeCache.txt? Checked CMakeError.log?

Comment: It fails only for cross-compilation (to iOS).

Comment: I didn't get that from your question. Do you mind to edit title and question to point out this important detail?

Comment: Just found that out later - but yes.

Comment: Do you actually need all the stuff from FindGit? Or would find_program be enough?

Comment: Cross-compilation is a factor here. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294056/cmake-using-find-package-cross-compiling/) asks about similar things, and my answer to it is applicable for your case too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake using find\_package() cross compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294056/cmake-using-find-package-cross-compiling)