# CMake find_path works on Linux but not on MingW. How do I fix this?

Tags: linux, path, cmake, find

On a Linux system:

Execute the following commands:

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir mingw linux files
touch files/blah
```

Add the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
PROJECT(TEST LANGUAGES CXX)

find_path(BLAH_DIR
    blah
    PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files
)
message(STATUS "BLAH_DIR=${BLAH_DIR}")
```

In the "mingw" folder run cmake with a mingw toolchain file like the following:

```
# the name of the target operating system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres)

# here is the target environment located
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 )

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search 
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

In the "linux" folder, simply run cmake.

For MingW we get:

```
BLAH_DIR=BLAH_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

For Linux we get:

```
BLAH_DIR=/Development/test/files
```

as expected.

Why doesn't find_path work for MingW?
Should I submit a bug report on CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Tsyvarev for the helpful info.

The answer to the part of the title which says "How do I fix this?" is to specify NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and NO_DEFAULT_PATH in the find_path command.

Answer (score 1):

It is written in your toolchain file:

> search headers and libraries in the **target environment**

Command `find_path` searches headers, so it looks under `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32` only.

Even *PATH* option is prepended with that root path. So it cannot find a file located in the source tree.

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_path.html) for `find_path` command, and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294056/cmake-using-find-package-cross-compiling/41297449#41297449) to related question.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and missed, in the wall of text, the bit that said that the root path is prepended to everything. (I forgot to ask) how do I solve this?

Comment: `how do I solve this?` - E.g., remove line `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)` from the toolchain, so host environment will be searched too.

Comment: That won't work as I am using find_path which could be any file, not necessarily an include file, and secondly it may bugger up my cross-compile by including files from the host system which should only be included from the target system.

Comment: I need to use NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and     NO_DEFAULT_PATH in the  find_path command.