# cmake find module exclude system folders

Tags: android, cmake

I'm trying to use my cmake build system for my project and adapt everything so that I'm able to build for android too.
Currently, my cmake files search for the necessary libraries, and if not found, instead of building the main library, it downloads these dependencies using ExternalProject_Add, builds them, and installs them to a ThirdParty folder.
This ThirdParty folder is added to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH before all these find_package calls.
So, when you try to build a second time, the libraries are found in the ThirdParty directory, and the main library builds ok.

Now, I plan to build for android, so I want to ignore ALL libraries already found on the system, since I'm going to have  to recompile them for arm. How can I make find_package completely ignore the normal / prefix, and just use the prefix I specify with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ?
I tried setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH instead of appending, but it still finds my system libraries.

Comment: Do you **cross-compile** for android? If so, you may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294056/cmake-using-find-package-cross-compiling/41297449#41297449) useful.

Comment: Get that as an answer and I will definitely mark it as accepted. Even when not cross-compiling, that's exactly what I wanted, to make sure I find my version of the libraries, compiled with my options.